# i am trying to play video from php, but unable to do so

Tags: javascript, python, php, css, jquery-ui

this is my php which generate video url, i want that url should be played. please add a code in it so that i can play it in iptv player.

```html
<?php
// usage main.php?c=123
$input = $_GET["c"];
if (!$input){
   exit("Channel ID not found");
}
$channel_meta = JsonfromURI("https://catalogapi.com/v1/channel/${input}");
$stream_url = $channel_meta->stream_url_hls;
$tok_json = JsonfromURI("https://useraction.com/token/live.php");
$video_token = $tok_json->video_token;
$m3u8 = $stream_url.$video_token;
echo $m3u8;

function JsonfromURI($url) {
   $resp = file_get_contents($url);       
   return json_decode($resp);
};
```

Comment: https://catalogapi.com/v1/channel/123 returns HTML, not JSON.

Comment: Can you please edit in my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This PHP Looks like it is sending back an URL String in HTML Format. I do not see where this PHP is called from your JavaScript or your main page. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: IS IT OK TO SHARE COMPLETE CODE IN PRIVATE MESSAGE ?